# How to set file permissions with touch command

Tags: files, permissions, touch

It seems that whenever I create a file with `touch` the permissions are set to: **-rw-r--r--**.

Is there some way that I can configure the permissions with `touch` or does this have to be done after with a different command?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can modify your `umask` to allow (for most implementations) more read/write privileges, but not executable, since generally the requested permissions are `0666`.

If your `umask` is `022`, you'll see `touch` make a `0644` file.

Interestingly, [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/touch.html) describes this behavior in terms of `creat`:

> 1. If file does not exist:
>
>    The [creat()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/creat.html) function is called with the following arguments:
>
>    - The file operand is used as the path argument.
>    - The value of the bitwise-inclusive *OR* of **`S_IRUSR`**, **`S_IWUSR`**, **`S_IRGRP`**, **`S_IWGRP`**, **`S_IROTH`**, and **`S_IWOTH`** is used as the mode argument.

and it is only by following the links to `creat`, then to `open`, noticing the mention of `umask` and back-tracking to `open` (and `creat`) to verify that `umask` is supposed to affect `touch`.

For `umask` to affect only the `touch` command, use a subshell:

```
(umask 066; touch private-file)
(umask 0; touch world-writable-file)
touch file-as-per-current-umask
```

(note that in any case, if the file existed beforehand, `touch` will not change its permissions, just update its timestamps).

Answer (score 3):

You can manipulate the `umask`. Generally it's set to `022` which means when a user creates a file, it will get permission of `0644`, you can manipulate `umask` according to your needs.